# How to customize hotkeys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I want to customize hotkeys, but in a special way.
There should be global shortcuts, like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but I want to create window specific shortcuts.

For example:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> in chrome, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> does <kbd>PageUp</kbd> in LibreOffice.

It would be nice if global settings didn't work, except some windows specified.

Is there an application for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether my answer satisfies you completely! But you can give a try to this option. You'll get a lot of configuration to set your own `Shortcut Key` in order to make your task easier.

Follow these steps:

- Open `Keyboard` from `System Settings` (Search in *dash*)
- Chose <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> tab
- Go to `Navigation` you will get a bunch of options to set.
- You should also try other `options` from the list. I am attaching a screenshot give a loot at that! So start digging it..

[image]

Hope it helps you somewhat!! Reply for further assistance.